# Animated Image with python

Tags: python, animation, graphics

so I'm trying to learn python by using it, and I started to code the famous DVD_logo animation, with a background constantly changing color.
The first time I did it I used the "Pygame" library, but it works a little bit slower.
I don't know how to search for a better library for my purpose of maybe how to improve my program.
I actually modified it, handling the refreshing background with a limited surface, but it seems not to work. There's the code, just keep in mind is my first attempt, so maybe there's something strange or some commented statement (I was just trying)

```
import random
import sys
import os
import pygame
import random
from PIL import Image


time_exit = 3000

pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()

win_width = 800#1440#817#980
win_height = 420#855#417#500#
logo_s_w = 134
logo_s_h = 67
logo_w = random.Random()
logo_h = random.Random()
logo_w = logo_w.uniform(0 + logo_s_w, win_width - logo_s_w)
logo_h = logo_h.uniform(0 + logo_s_h, win_height - logo_s_h)
logo_w = int(logo_w)
logo_h = int(logo_h)
back_w = logo_w
back_h = logo_h
past_h = 0
past_w = 0

moving_pixel = 3
coverage_pixel_w = logo_s_w + moving_pixel * 10
coverage_pixel_h = logo_s_h + moving_pixel * 10
mov_cov = moving_pixel * 2

red = (
    255, 0, 0)

rgb = random.Random()

rgb = [
    0, 100, 0
    ]
r = random.Random()
b = random.Random()
g = random.Random()

x_flag = bool(random.getrandbits(1))
y_flag = bool(random.getrandbits(1))

hit = False

def logo(x,y):
   win.blit(dvdImg, (x,y))

def back(x,y):
   win.blit(back_rec, (x,y))

black = (
    0, 0, 0)

#clock = pygame.time.Clock()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
#win = pygame.Surface((win_width, win_height)).convert_alpha()

dvdImg = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('DVD_logo.gif'),[logo_s_w, logo_s_h])


pygame.display.set_caption('DVD')

background_colour = (rgb)
win.fill(background_colour)
#bg_image = pygame.Surface((logo_s_w, logo_s_h))
#win.fill(black)
bg_image = pygame.Surface((logo_s_w, logo_s_h))
logo(logo_w, logo_h)
back_rec = pygame.Surface((coverage_pixel_w, coverage_pixel_h))
pygame.display.flip()


time = 0

running = True

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    hit = False
    #bg_image = pygame.Surface((logo_s_w, logo_s_h))
    #pygame.draw.rect(bg_image, background_colour, [logo_w, logo_h, logo_s_w, logo_s_h])
    #pygame.draw.rect(bg_image, (255,192,0), [200, 0, 200, 200])
    #win.fill(background_colour)


    back_rec.fill(rgb)
    back(back_w, back_h)
    logo(logo_w, logo_h)
    pygame.display.update()
    #clock.tick(60)
    back_w = logo_w - past_w
    back_h = logo_h + past_h

    if logo_w < win_width and not x_flag:
        logo_w = logo_w + moving_pixel
        past_w = + moving_pixel + mov_cov

    if logo_w > 0 and x_flag:
        logo_w = logo_w - moving_pixel
        past_w = - moving_pixel + mov_cov

    if logo_w <= 0:
        x_flag = False
        hit = True

    if logo_w >= (win_width - (logo_s_w)):
        x_flag = True
        hit = True

    if logo_h < win_height and not y_flag:
        logo_h = logo_h + moving_pixel
        past_h = + moving_pixel - mov_cov

    if logo_h > 0 and y_flag:
        logo_h = logo_h - moving_pixel
        past_h = 0 - moving_pixel - mov_cov

    if logo_h <= 0:
        y_flag = False
        hit = True

    if logo_h >= (win_height - (logo_s_h)):
        y_flag = True
        hit = True

    #change color
    if hit:
        rgb[0] = r.uniform(0, 255) 
        rgb[1] = g.uniform(0, 255) 
        rgb[2] = b.uniform(0, 255) 
        background_colour = tuple(rgb)
        win.fill(background_colour)
        #background_colour = background_colour(rgb)
        #rgb = list(rgb)
        hit = False

    #pygame.time.delay()
#    time = time + 1
    if time > time_exit:
        sys.exit()

#running = True
#while running:
#  for event in pygame.event.get():
#    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
#      running = False

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: I guess your mainloop should be `while running`?

Comment: yes, I didn't used a main loop, is this a problem?

Comment: you didn't use `running` at all so I was a bit confused ... how do you exit the program? It looks like the purpose of `running` is to control the gameloop but I can't see any usage of it.

Comment: I end it with a time control, but it's "manual", I used it only to make some try. But the main problem is the slow execution, I don't know how to solve it